# can't go on to multiplayer on minecraft pe version 0.8.1

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just bought minecraft pe version 0.8.1 on my new samsung galaxy tab 3 that I got for xmas, the singleplayer worlds work fine, but when I try to connect to a server it doesn't work. My wifi and internet are both very fast, and the server I tried to connect to first is a server I go on, on my pc. I don't know if it doesn't work BECAUSE I use it on the pc but im still quite concerned. I tried another server but still doesn't connect. Everytime I try it comes up with: "can't connect to world". Please help!!

Comment: i do not play minecraft anymore but is it possible that server can reject mobile clients?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the PC version as a server on your computer.  You need to have the pocket edition PE version server loaded on your computer.  I don't think you can join your iPad to your computer server.